# How to add a custom subclass of uiview as a subview to another custom subclass of uiview in code?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am an absolute newbie at ios programming so forgive me:

I have a subclass of UIView called PuzzlePiece that I want to represent just a single puzzle piece (obviously).  I don't want to use a nib file for it, but just want to be able to draw a piece using code and display it.

I have a view controller and associated nib file that will hold the entire puzzle.  The view in the nib is of type PuzzleView which is another class that I have defined as a custom subclass of UIView.  My PuzzleView works fine and I can draw on it and everything.  I have a property of type PuzzlePiece called piece that I figured can refer to my puzzle piece.

So all I am trying to figure out how to do is to now initialize my view, add it as a subview, and draw it on the screen.  Sounds simple, but I am at a complete loss of how to make this work.  I would totally believe that I am not even approaching the problem correctly, so if that is the case, please advise me!

I thought I should be able to do something like

```
piece = [[puzzlePiece alloc] initWithFrame: ... ];
[self addSubview:piece];
```

But... the init bit doesn't work... and really no init methods seem to be available to me.

So... yeah.  How do I just add a custom subclass of uiview as a subview to another custom subclass of uiview in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to capitalize puzzlePiece?

```
PuzzlePiece *piece = [[PuzzlePiece alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

If PuzzlePiece derives from UIView then your code looks like it should work.

Comment: I get a error on the line that says something about a forward declaration.  :/

Comment: You may need to `#include "PuzzlePiece.h"` in this file.

Comment: Yup it was the include.  Stupid mistake.  Thanks for your help!